# How much data should I store in an object locally? Trying to limit requests to database

Tags: database, react-native, amazon-s3

I am currently fetching images from my aws S3 account. The issue is I will be fetching a lot of images which naturally requires a lot of requests.

In order to keep my requests down, I have been considering fetching a list of all the images I need when the app loads and storing them in an object where I can then filter the images I need throughout the app.

**My questions are:**

- How much data can you store in a local object before performance
  drops?
- Considering scalability, is this something I should be concerned
  about or is this something where I just need to eat the cost? How
  does instagram deal with all their images? Are they making a ton of
  requests?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own way to cache images, try using [react native fast image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) instead. It uses Glide for Android and SDWebImage for iOS under the hood and offers an out-of-the-box way to handle image caching.